# User registration plugin listening

Tags: users

How can I listen in my plugin to see if

```
craft()->on('users.saveUser', function(Event $event) {
```

onsaveUser came from front end creation or control panel ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the request service. *craft()->request->isCpRequest()* or *craft()->request ->isSiteRequest()*

https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#isCpRequest-detail